# Counter-example for existence of an isomorphism between ordered sets.

Tags: order-theory

Take two totally ordered sets $(A,\leq_A)$ and $(B,\leq_B)$. Assume that none of them have neither a maximum nor a minimum. Assume that $A$ is isomorphic to some final segment of $B$ and $B$ is isomorphic to some final segment of $A$. How to choose $A$ and $B$ so that they are not isomorphic ?
I don't think it is a difficult question but I can see it and I need a new point of view.

I assume  $A$ and $B$ to have no extrema since I don't want to take $A=\mathbb{R}$ and $B=[0;1[$ for instance.

I would be very happy if the counter example involves dense orders.

Comment: What do you mean by "final segment"?

Comment: I would suppose that it was something like the upper member of a Dedekind cut. (?)

Comment: "Assume that none of them have neither a maximum nor a minimum." So each ordered set has either a min or max? Double negatives are confusing. Is a final segment a filter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)), or an upward-closed subset in general?

Comment: Here what I call "final segment" is something as the answer provided by William Elliot. More precisely, a final segment of $A$ is a cofinal convex subset of $A$. One may be cautious : if $A$ does not have the GLB property, a final segment may not be written as $\{x|x>a\}$ or $\{x|x\geq a\}$.

Comment: Actually, if it is difficult to give a counter-example it may be because $A$ and $B$ are elementary equivalent in the sense of the theory of dense orders without maximal nor minimal element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordinal sum $Z$ of two (disjoint) partial orders $X$ and $Y$, written as $Z=X\oplus Y$, is defined by $a\leq b$ if one of the following holds:

1. $a,b\in X$ and $a\leq_X b$
2. $a,b\in Y$ and $a\leq_Y b$
3. $a\in X$ and $b\in Y$

Intuitively, it's like stacking the Hasse diagrams of two partial orders on top of each other. An infinite ordinal sum can be defined similarly. Then we can define $A=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{R}\oplus\cdots$ and $B=\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\cdots$. Then each order is clearly isomorphic to a final segment of the other, and $A$ and $B$ cannot themselves be isomorphic, since if we take any element in the first occurrence of $\mathbb{R}$ in $B$, say $0$, then that element has the property that the subposet of all elements below it is a dense order, while no element of $A$ has that property.

Comment: That's a good example. Then if I now take $\mathbb Q$ instead of $\mathbb Z$ then I will have my dense orders.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a final segment is { x : x > a }, let A be the reals ordered by magnitude and B = (-oo,0] $\cup$ = [1,oo).

Comment: In this case $B$ is not isomorphic to a final segment of $A$... In particular $A$ is a dense order and $B$ is not.